# Wordpress Gutenberg .updateBlock

Tags: wordpress, plugins, block, wordpress-gutenberg

There is method I believe I can use for my need. However I need an example of it using:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-editor/#updateBlockAttributes
how this is possible? Anyone has it maybe?

Comment: Gutenberg has a lack of practical examples...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the (very tiny) documentation on the function in the [Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-block-editor/#updateBlockAttributes). Here is an live example from my own code at a [new slider block for wordpress](https://gutenslider.org). It uses the `withDispatch` higher order component to feed components with actions.

```
withDispatch( ( dispatch, ownProps, registry ) => {

  return {
    updateEditable( isEditing ) {
      const { clientId, setAttributes } = ownProps;
      const { getBlockOrder } = registry.select( 'core/block-editor' );
      const { updateBlockAttributes } = dispatch( 'core/block-editor' );

      //update own isEditable
      setAttributes( { isEditing } );

      const innerBlockIds = getBlockOrder( clientId );
      innerBlockIds.forEach( ( innerBlockId ) => {
        updateBlockAttributes( innerBlockId, {
         isEditing,
        } );
      } );
    },
  };
} )
```

To play around with the wordpress data module, that offers data about the editor or blocks to the client, you can also make use of the `wp.data`-Module. When in the backend, You can e.g. go to a browser console, and type `wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).updateBlockAttributes()` to test what the function does.

You can also have a look in the gutenberg github repository. Core Blocks also use `updateBlockAttributes`. E.g. in [columns](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/5494bc57fc77de6cada4295823a3fb047e168f89/packages/block-library/src/column/edit.js#L98)

If you want more information on data handling in gutenberg, you can read this very good blob post, that introduces the wp.data api and also the concept of `withSelect` and `withDispatch` higher order components.